# Saving Nodelist and access via js array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, node.js, dom

I am running a PHP script which collects data from a URL and displays the specified html tag in a node. Now I want to save this list on my server and create a js function which accesses this file and collects certain data e.g. starting from the 6th line every third value should be put in a array which will be displayed.

So I want to connect the PHP data I am getting from a URL with my js script which currently displays only static values in an array but it should get these values from my PHP list.

This is the code I have for PHP:

```
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/link");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName('td');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue."<br>"; // return <td> tag data
}
```

The output looks like this, since the table will only have 3 columns

Date
Time
Name
26.4.17
13:45
**sometext**
26.4.17
13:45
**sometext**

I want the js to only get the bolded values for the date today in an array.
My idea was to save it as xml file and create js access but that didn't work the way I wanted. Does anybody know how to do this?
Here is the structure of the HTML Table

```
<table class="xxx"><col style="width: 20%;"/>
    <col style="width: 20%;"/><col style="width: 60%;"/>
    <thead>
        <tr><td>Date</td><td>Time</td><td>Name</td></tr>
    </thead> 
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>2017-06-26</td><td>03:06:13</td><td>thetextiwant</td></tr>
        <tr><td>2017-06-26</td><td>03:06:13</td><td>thetextiwant</td></tr>
```

This table will be continued for another 1000 values
and then

```
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you tell and show us a little more about what your tried? Because from your question it is not entirely clear to me what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Well, I want data which is coming from an external url. I get this data with the php script. Now I need to sort it that I only get the "sometext" values and then I want to write a javascript function which reads those values and returns them in an array.

Comment: Okay, that's a bit broad for one question. So, I would suggest we keep this question about extracting the data from the DOM and then you ask another separate question on StackOverflow about the JavaScript part. So tell us, how do you identify where "sometext" is? Is it always the third column of every row? Or can that change? If it's more complicated, can you edit your question and show us a snippet of the actual HTML code, so we can identify which part exactly you want to extract?

Comment: Yea okay sure. No its very simple. The table has 3 Columns every time and I want only the values of the 3rd column without header. the length might variable from time to time but I think that doesnt matter

Comment: Right, okay. About the header, is that a regular `<tr><td>` structure as well? Or is it perhaps `<thead><tr><th>' or something else even perhaps? I think it would help if you could post an example of the actual table (doesn't have to contain actual data though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, to get every third column of that table structure you could do a few things:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$tbodyRows = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'tbody' )
                 ->item( 0 ) // grab first tbody
                 ->getElementsByTagName( 'tr' );

$result = array();
foreach( $tbodyRows as $tbodyRow )
{
    $result[] = $tbodyRow->getElementsByTagName( 'td' )
                         ->item( 2 ) // grab 3rd column
                         ->nodeValue;
}

var_dump( $result );
```

or (with [xpath](https://php.net/manual/class.domxpath.php)):

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $dom );
$thirdColumns = $xpath->query( '//table/tbody/tr/td[3]' );

$result = array();
foreach( $thirdColumns as $thirdColumn )
{
    $result[] = $thirdColumn->nodeValue;
}

var_dump( $result );
```

Comment: I've got to go now, will edit later today, if you need to identify the table by it's class as well.

Comment: Okay, it works and now I have it in an array which is quite nice. It looks like this. Is it possible to save this file now and acces it via javascript or should here ask a new question ? output lookslike this: { [0]=> string(21) "thetextiwant" [1]=> string(22) "thetextiwant" [2]=> string(13)  }

Comment: @erik7 Yeah, you should ask new questions about those things or use the search function; there's probably loads of questions already about saving data to a file in PHP and having JavaScript request data from PHP (search the tag [tag:ajax] for that as well).